# Getting next sibling element using XPath and Selenium for Java

Tags: java, xml, selenium, xpath

I know that you can get a parent element when using Selenium for Java and XPath like this:

```
WebElement parent = child.findElement(By.xpath(".."));
```

But how do I get the next sibling of an element, what do I need to put between the parentheses instead of two dots as in the case above?

Comment: Not sure if you are looking for `following-sibling` function. Provide the `html` of what you are trying to accomplish if possible.

Comment: variant: `preceding-sibling` or `preceding`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use [`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) axis :

```
WebElement followingSibling = child.findElement(By.xpath("following-sibling::*"));
```

List of available axes by MDN, for further reference : [Mozilla Developer Network : Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)

Comment: And to get only the next sibling, use `following-sibling::*[1]`.

Comment: will this quite probably deliver a text element?

Answer (score 7):

WebElement parent = child.findElement(By.xpath("following-sibling::*[X]"));

X will be the **Xth** sibling of that element.

Comment: Should be **Xth**?